# Searching Algoritm

Tags: java

I write this code but I don't know why doesn't work.

```
static boolean findeText(String text1, String text2) {

    char c1[] = text1.toCharArray();
    char c2[] = text2.toCharArray();
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= c1.length - c2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, h = i; j <= c2.length; j++, h++) {
            if (i == c2.length) {
                return true;
            }
            if (c1[h] != c2[j]) {
                b = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

I want find text 2 in text 1 and after that return true or false.

Comment: What's your test case? What do you get? What do you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check if some string contains any other string, just use `contains()` method.

In your case that would be

```
return text1.contains(text2);
```

Plus you should always write your code in defensive way. That means you should always make sure there will be no `NullPointerException` etc. So in your particular case if someone pass either null text1 or null text2, your program will crash.

Comment: Thank u but I don't want use other methods

Answer (score 1):

Above you had NPE in line

> if (c1[h] != c2[j])

I have modified your code slightly to get output as requirement.

```
static boolean findeText(String text1, String text2) {
        if ((text1== null) ||(text2==null) || (text1.isEmpty()) || (text2.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            return false;
        }
        char c1[] = text1.toCharArray();
        char c2[] = text2.toCharArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= c1.length - c2.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < c2.length; j++) {
                if (c1[i + j] == c2[j]) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                if (count == c2.length) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code has a few flaws that prevent it from correctly locating the second text within the first. Here are some suggestions for improvements:

```
static boolean findText(String text1, String text2) {

    char c1[] = text1.toCharArray();
    char c2[] = text2.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i <= c1.length - c2.length; i++) {
        boolean b = true;
        for (int j = 0, h = i; j < c2.length; j++, h++) {
            if (c1[h] != c2[j]) {
                b = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (b) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```